# PHP generated calendar in Google Calendar - not valid URL

Tags: php, apache, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am a bit new to PHP.

I am trying to filter a ICS file for events containing a certain string. The following script seems to do that job just fine:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fodda2009.ics');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

function icsFilter($paramUrl,$filterstring) {
    $icsFile = file_get_contents($paramUrl);

    $icsData = explode("BEGIN:", $icsFile);

    foreach($icsData as $value) {
        if (strpos($value, "VEVENT") === FALSE) {
            echo "BEGIN:";
            echo $value;
        }
        else {
            if (strpos($value, $filterstring) !== FALSE) {
                echo "BEGIN:";
                echo $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
<?php echo icsFilter('http://cal.laget.se/ALMTUNAISHOCKEYSKOLA.ics','dda 2009'); ?>
VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:Dummy info
DTEND;TZID=W. Europe Standard Time:20001010T121500
DTSTAMP:20001005T192952Z
DTSTART;TZID=W. Europe Standard Time:20001010T110000
SUMMARY:Dummy event
UID:200abc01010T110000-8918999@stackoverflow.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I am hosting the script at http://mydomain.dyndns.com/mycalendar.php. When I enter that URL into Google Calendar (other calendars -> add by URL) I receive a message "[your URL] is not a valid URL".

Is this caused by the script ending in .php?

Do I need to convince my server (Apache) to call the php script at a http://mydomain.dyndns.com/mycalendar.ics URL? How? Is there something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: file extensions in urls are meaningless. the `Content-type` header is what matters. you could rename `kittens.jpg` to `kittens.exe`, tell your webserver that `.exe` files are image/jpeg, and your browser will happily display the picture.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a little embarrassing...

The code above works just fine, the source of my error was that I left out the "http://" from the URL. Thus Google Calendar complained that it wasn't a good URL. *cough* Adding "http://" to my URL worked wonders :)

I'll leave the script here, maybe someone else wants to have a simple PHP script to filter an existing iCal file and serve it to Google Calendar.